# "Break" Table whit css if possible

Tags: jquery, css

I have table that is dynamically created by pulling data from SQL DB with VBscript and then forwarded to HTML with AJAX and JQuery.

This is how my HTML looks:

```
    <table width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
       <tr bgcolor="#FF9933" > 
         <td width="50%" style="border-right:solid 1px black">TD 1</td>
         <td width="50%">TD 2</td>
       </tr>
  </table>
    <table id="UpdatePanel" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
      </table>
```

Table with id "UpdatePanel" is filled with Data that is dynamically pulled whit ajax.

The tables:
This is how my table looks and how the data is shown
[image: This is how my table looks and how the data is shown]

This is how i want it to look, i want to "break" it after lets say 26-27 rows
[image: This is how i want it to look, i want to "break" it after lets say 26-27 rows]

I don't know if you can accomplish this just with CSS or CSS and JQuery or with something else.

Comment: you're using two tables right?... can you change their width to `45%` each and try using `float:left`..

Comment: That would be to easy and i wont need your help :),yes i use two tables but one is just for the column names and other for data.If you look at the pictures better you will see what i'm talking about.Ty anyway.

Comment: you may use a insert  few tbody element that will hold 26/27 tr .  these tbody elements can then be displayed as cell or inline-tables. http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/grmqjB

Comment: @GCyrillus This is what i get from ajax `<tr><td width='50%' style='border-right:solid 1px black;border-bottom:solid 1px black ;color:#000'>Help me</td><td width='50%' style='border-bottom:solid 1px black;color:#000'> blah</td></tr>` , number of tr's like this depend on how much data i have in db table(how much "help me " and "blah" raws  i have in sql db) so ,how can i insert tbody when i don't know how many tr's will i get from ajax.As i sad table tr's and td's are generated dynamically.Ty anyway .

Comment: let your script count the datas and insert these extra tag only where you want to split it (it can be on server side if this where tds are generated ) actually you could just close and reopen thhe table tag every x datas retrieved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't something CSS can do, cleanly at least. I recommend splitting the data after ajax success and creating multiple tables.

```
function createTables(data){
     var $tr = $(data)    
     var size = 26;
     while($tr.length > 0){
        var table = $('<table></table>').append($tr.splice(0,size))
        $('body').append(table)
     }
}
```

And then `float:left` or `display:inline-block` on your tables.

example:
https://jsfiddle.net/guanzo/rw59c65b/

Comment: display:inline-table to keep the table-layout efficient .... just  like i suggested via comments . keeping th on top can be usefull too https://jsfiddle.net/rw59c65b/1/ ;)